# Wall oven install. Wires from wall are 2 black 1 gray and an aluminum ground

Tags: wiring, walls, oven

Installing new wall oven.  Wires from wall are 2 heavy gauge black 1 gray and 1 aluminum ground.  New oven has black white red and green wires. If I attach one black  to the oven black, one black to the oven red, the gray to be he oven white and ground to ground will it be right?  Thanks.

Comment: What size breaker are the two black wires attached to in the panel, and what size breaker does the new oven documentation or label say it requires?

Answer (score 7):

You have the right idea.

However if the ground is aluminum, so are the other wires. That's fine for big stuff like this, but **you must follow The rules with aluminum.**

1. put the aluminum wire on terminals rated for aluminum.  Not random wire nuts.
2. torque screw terminals to the specification, for real, with a torque driver. Because experience shows this matters for *all* connections.

One way to go is Polaris couplers, but those are costly.  However the ILSCO "Mac Block Connector" is a more affordable (if difficult to find) "mini Polaris connector" for wires up to #6.

Or, convert your oven to a cord-and-plug connection, using a NEMA 14-50 socket that is rated for aluminum and 75C thermal.  (Most are).  Then you install a regular old NEMA 14-50 range cord on your oven.

As said, torque screws to spec if you want a reliable connection.  Aluminum has been trouble-free for 60 years on large connections, because it has always been industry practice to torque them to spec.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds good.

Neutral wire must be white or grey, but white or grey could be used as hot(should be marked, if it is).  This changes with large size feeder wires, where you can use other colours for neutral(black with white tape.

Bare or green(maybe a yellow stripe) are ground.

Most other colours can be use for hot.  Black and red are common.

This is for North American systems only.  Other systems like Europe uses different colour schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Attach one black to the oven black, one black to the oven red, the gray to the oven white and ground to ground.

Would be correct wiring,

giving the oven 240 and 120 volt

120 V is for the electronics

240 V (2 phase) is for the heating elements.